Rust spots above windshield
Noticed these rust spots on a 2013 VW Passat. I've been to three body shops for an estimate:

shop 1 says they can just sand it off and touch it up and claim that should be good enough
shop 2 says they'd have to take the windshield out, check and clean that whole area, repaint the entire roof, then put in a new windshield. ~$2500 estimate
shop 3 says the same as above, but they told me there's a good chance the windshield will survive and can be reused, so I wouldn't pay for a new one. ~$1800 estimate (without windshield)

Location is Germany.
I don't care about it looking great, I want to make sure nothing continues to rust in that area though as otherwise the car is in great shape and I want to keep it for another few years.
Is it worth shelling out for the full windshield removal job just to be sure nothing is missed? I don't want to go for the cheaper option and then find a hole hidden behind the headliner in a few years.




Use Shop #1.  Apply a liquid rust "neutralizer" that will seep deep into the cracked area and thus abate the progression of rust.  Sand and paint afterwards.  I've used this technique on cars in the past and the rust never returned, even years later.  It's what is recommended by large auto manufacturers like GM.
